# How to plot the kernel in Z-axis from Support Vector Machine?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, scatter-plot

I have made a Support Vector Machine code and I want to plot the scatter plot with the kernel on the Z-axis.

First of all, here is my code.

```
% Clear
clear all
close all

% Test data and labels y
X = [1 2; 1 1; 2 1; 7 7; 8 7; 7 8];
y = [1;1;1;-1;-1;-1];

% How many labels
m = size(y, 1);

% Polynomial kernel 2:nd
K = @(x1,x2) (1 + x1*x2').^2;

% Construct the gram-matrix Q
Q = zeros(m,m);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:m
        Q(i,j) = y(i)*y(j)*K(X(i,:), X(j,:));
    end
end

% Create QP-solution
c = -ones(m, 1);
A = y';
b = 0;
[x, solution] = quadprog(Q, c, A, b);

% Create bias and weights for the hyper plane
epsilon = 1e-6;
sv_idx = find(x > epsilon);
b = mean(y(sv_idx) - X(sv_idx,:)*X'*diag(y)*x);
w = X'*diag(y)*x;

% Create the hyper plane
[x1, x2] = meshgrid(min(X(:, 1)):max(X(:, 1)), min(X(:, 2)):max(X(:, 2)));
z = zeros(size(x1));
for i = 1:size(x1,1)
    for j = 1:size(x2,2)
        z(i,j) = -w(1)*x1(i,j) - w(2)*x2(i,j) - b;
    end
end

% Plot the hyper plane
surf(x1, x2, z, 'EdgeColor','none');
view(3);

% Plot the measurements
hold on
scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), y, 50, y, 'filled');
```

The function **quadprog** can be found [here](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/Optimization/quadprog.c) .

I have a matrix called `X`. It has `6` rows and `2` columns. Every row is a measurement and `y` determine if it's class `1` or class `-1`. The class label in other words.

The problem with `X` is that it's on the second dimension, I need to have it onto the third dimension 3D. So therefore, I could use a kernel to give my matrix `X` another column of data.

```
K = @(x1,x2) (1 + x1*x2').^2;
```

But the problem is that `K` is a matrix, and not an `extra` column for `X`. Which makes it harder to plot my scatter data as you can see here.

```
 scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), y, 50, y, 'filled');
```

When I plot `scatter3`, the measurements are placed `exactly` `-1` to `1` away from the hyperplane, because `y` only contains negative ones and positive ones.

[image]

**Question:**

If I have a matrix `X` and I transform it into `Q` due to the quadratic programming process. But I need to plot the deepth of the scatter plot, not only use `-1` and `1` as the Z-axis values.

How can I get the `deepth` of the scatter plot? I need to have the correct values for the Z-axsis.

If you don't know what support vector machine is, then this picture explains that there is a hyperplane who separate two different classes.

[image]